# How can I use bat command as an alternative to tail command?

Tags: command-line, bash, tail

I love the syntax highlighting of `cat`. So I want to use it as an alternative to `tail` command. But I cannot find a generic way to accomplish this. But I can use this command as an alternative to `tail` if I know the line numbers of the file.

e.g: if a file named `test.log` contains 90 lines, I can use the following command to print the last 10 lines.

```bash
batcat --line-range "80:" test.log
```

But I can't do the same if I don't know the line numbers of file. Is there any other way?

Comment: Please try: `cat test.log | tail -n10` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tail -n10` is the proper shortest answer, but to do it by running `batcat`:

```
batcat --line-range $(expr $(wc -l /etc/hosts | cut -d" " -f 1) - 1): /etc/hosts
```

You just change the -1 to whatever number of lines you want -1, so if you want 10 you set it to -9. The ":" in batcat doesn't take negative number, so no shortcut.